# Element not visible after navigating using playwright

Tags: javascript, node.js, automated-tests, playwright

I am using playwright to do my browser automation.

I click a hyperlink which takes me to Google.com and there I want to verify "Google Search" button exists after navigation.
Here is my code.

```
const textToClick = "Visit Google"
const textToVerify = "Google Search"
const elements = await page.$$(`text=${textToClick}`)
await element[0].click()
const elements = await page.$$(`text=${textToVerify}`)
const elementLength = elements.length
console.log("Element Length::",elementLength, ":: TexToFind::",textToVerify)
```

When I run it with mocha test, "Google Search" button is not found.

But when I run same code through visual studio debugger under node's main entry file(`main.js`); I am able to find "Google Search" button.

Here is playwright debugger's output from mocha test run:

> pw:api => page.goto started +0ms
> pw:api navigating to "file:///C:/devel/devspace/js/myAutomation/test/src/sampleApp.html", waiting until "load" [] +3ms
> pw:api navigated to "file:///C:/devel/devspace/js/myAutomation/test/src/sampleApp.html" [] +348ms
> pw:api "domcontentloaded" event fired [] +7ms
> pw:api "load" event fired [] +276ms
> pw:api <= page.goto succeeded +6ms
> pw:api => elementHandle.click started +364ms
> pw:api attempting elementHandle.click action [] +2ms
> pw:api   waiting for element to be visible, enabled and not moving [] +2ms
> pw:api   element is visible, enabled and does not move [] +479ms
> pw:api   scrolling into view if needed [] +1ms
> pw:api   done scrolling [] +63ms
> pw:api   checking that element receives pointer events at (358.64,558.1) [] +66ms
> pw:api   element does receive pointer events [] +188ms
> pw:api   performing elementHandle.click action [] +2ms
> pw:api   elementHandle.click action done [] +83ms
> pw:api   waiting for scheduled navigations to finish [] +3ms
> pw:api navigated to "https://www.google.com/" [] +293ms
> pw:api   navigations have finished [] +46ms
> pw:api <= elementHandle.click succeeded +2ms
> sleeping
> sleeping finished
> element Length:: 0 :: TexToFind:: Google Search
> 1) Test Click Functionality on Hyperlink

*You will notice element Length is zero indicating "Google Search" button is not found*

What is with mocha test that makes the element not searchable or is there something fundamental thing related to hyperlinks that needs to be handled when verifying elements after hyperlink click takes you to new webpage?

Comment: (1) Is the Google page opens on a new tab if you run your script with mocha? (2) Are you sure the Google page appears in English when it is opened by mocha?

Comment: yep Google opens in English and also it opens in same tab not new tab

Comment: Can't the scoping different between mocha and vs debugger runnings? I see you have two `const elements` maybe mocha is still looking for `textToClick` when it counts `0` as elements.length.

Comment: might be. Is there a way to check what is the scoping?

Comment: Just a guess, but it can be checked by rename the second `elements` to `elements2`, if it will work than the issue was the non-unique constant name for mocha.

Comment: ok thats a bad copy paste error. they are two different variables elements1, elements2.

Comment: @katch, can you share a more complete code snippet? I tried reproducing but failed. Additionally, I would recommend using page.waitForSelector instead of page.$$ since the former waits for the selector and returns an element handle. If you're on Playwright's slack community I'd be happy to assist you on IM.

Comment: thanks arjun for the tip. That slack link on playwright github is difficult to find. Now I am in will msg on the group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The click on the first link will cause a navigation. So you need to wait for the page to navigate to Google. You can do something like this:

```js
await Promise.all([elements[0].click(), page.waitForNavigation()]);
```

Comment: pw:api navigations have finished [] +46ms
pw:api <= elementHandle.click succeeded +2ms
indicates, navigation has succeeded. after which I am trying to verify. In my opinion we don't need to wait, as can be seen with debug runnings

Comment: When you debug you are giving the browser a few milliseconds to navigate to the next page.

Comment: I introduced sleeps as well, that didnt help either. I just now tried waiting for Navigation that didn't help either

Comment: ok, it indeed is due to not waiting for navigation to complete.